# PHP Object - Proper way to define a property with an If statement

Tags: php

Minimal example:

```
class Equipment
{
    public $Temp;

    function __construct($filter) {

        $this->Temp = 100;
        
        if(ContainsStringHelper($filter, "car")) {
            $this->Running = true;
        }
    }
}
```

You can see that I want to define `$this->Running` if the `$filter` variable contains the word `car`. If it does not, I don't want the property on the object.

This works, however PHPStorm throws a problem saying "Property declared dynamically":
[image]

I can get rid of that by declaring the property `public $Running`, but I don't want it to be a property on the object as `null` if the logic doesn't assign it a value.

Is there a proper way to do this?

Comment: I think PHPStorm is justified in trying to prevent you from having a property that only exists on some instances of a class. I understand that this might not seem like helpful feedback, but I'd try and rethink the business logic, or make do with the warning.

Comment: well surely you can suppress the phpstorm message with the annotations, but i'm not sure if doing this is a good practice since the ide would not know if the property exists or not

Comment: anyway then do `$this->{"Running"} = true`, is the same. 
however, you will not get the warning

Comment: `I don't want it to be a property on the object as null`...why not, exactly? That would be a more object-oriented and consistent way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution can be to declare the property and unset it during construction in your condition :

```
class Equipment
{
    public $Temp;
    public $Running = NULL;
    
    function __construct($filter) {

        $this->Temp = 100;

        if(ContainsStringHelper($filter, "car")) {
            $this->Running = true;
        } else {
            unset($this->Running) ;
        }
    }
}
```